# How to update JS Object for changes made in form data using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JS Object as following. I want to update it whenever any change is made in form elements. But as the name braces `"my_object[default][1][quick][position]"` dont convert to array, all input names are appended as string. What I try to accomplish is also given at end.
I have around 100 elements including input, select, radio, check boxes, etc. I am looking a dynamic way to update the object whenever any element is updated.

**HTML FORM ELEMENT**

```
<div class="col-12">
  <label class="card">
    <input name="my_object[default][1][quick][position]" class="checkable" value="text-left" type="radio" checked>
      <span class="my-details">
        Left
      </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**JS OBJECT TO BE UPDATED**

```
<script>

var my_object ={
    "default": {
        "1": {
            "data_src": "print1.jpg",
            "quick": {
                "a": "12",
                "b": "22",
                "position": "right"
            },
        "2": {
            "data_src": "print2.jpg",
            "quick": {
                "a": "10",
                "b": "20",
                "position": "center"
            }
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
$.each(formData, function () {

    if (my_object[this.name]) {
      if (!my_object[this.name].push) {
        my_object[this.name] = [my_object[this.name]];
      }
      my_object[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_object ={
    "default": {
        "1": {
            "data_src": "print1.jpg",
            "quick": {
                "a": "12",
                "b": "22",
                "position": "right"
                },
            },
        "2": {
            "data_src": "print2.jpg",
            "quick": {
                "a": "10",
                "b": "20",
                "position": "center"
            }
        }
    }
};

function updateMe(ths){
  eval($(ths).attr("data-jsonprop")+ "='" + $(ths).attr("value")+"'");
  console.log(my_object);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-12">
  <label class="card">
    <input name="radio1" data-jsonprop='my_object["default"]["1"]["quick"]["position"]' class="checkable" value="text-left" type="radio" onchange="updateMe(this)">
      <span class="my-details">
        Left
      </span>
  </label>
  
    <label class="card">
    <input name="radio1" data-jsonprop='my_object["default"]["1"]["quick"]["position"]' class="checkable" value="text-right" type="radio" onchange="updateMe(this)">
      <span class="my-details">
        Right
      </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your working answer. I will appreciate if you could post an answer without using **inline js** & **eval**.